# How to get parent dir in Makefile

Tags: makefile

This is printing the current dir, not the parent:

```
run:
    @cd ..; \
    echo $(shell pwd)
```

I need the parent dir in a command like:

```
run:
    @cd ..; \
    docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 -v $(shell pwd):/go/src/hello golang bash
```

Comment: Did you try `$$(pwd)` instead of `$(shell pwd)`?

Comment: I have no idea what I dit wrong before, that does actually work - thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that make works by invoking a shell and sending the recipe to the shell for execution.  Make doesn't have a shell "built in", so it's not running recipes directly.

The problem is that `$(shell ..)` is a make function.  All make variables and functions are expanded *before* the shell is invoked (consider: the shell doesn't know how to handle make functions).

That means that a make function like `$(shell ...)` is first expanded and `pwd` is run, which gives you the current directory that the make process is running in, then the resulting string is passed to the shell for execution.  So the shell sees this:

```
cd ..; echo /path/to/make/dir
```

You never need to use the `$(shell ...)` function *inside* a recipe; the recipe is already running in a shell!  Instead you want to use shell syntax inside a recipe.  The one caveat to this is that you have to escape dollar signs (replacing shell `$` with `$$`) so that make doesn't interpret them as make variables.  So if you write:

```
run:
    @cd ..; echo $$(pwd)
```

then make expands that string and sends this command to the shell:

```
cd ..; echo $(pwd)
```

which works as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the POSIXly mandated variable `PWD`?

```
run:
    @cd ..; echo $$PWD
```

Save a process today!